# Get database records in TYPO3 viewHelper

Tags: sql, typo3, query-builder, view-helpers

I want to create a database query in a view helper, this works with the following code:

```
$uid = 11;

$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_test_domain_model_author');
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select('*')
    ->addSelectLiteral(
      $queryBuilder->expr()->count('tx_test_domain_model_author.author', 'counter')
    )
    ->from('tx_test_domain_model_author')
    ->join(
      'tx_test_domain_model_author',
      'tx_test_publication_author_mm',
      'tx_test_publication_author_mm',
      $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
        'tx_test_domain_model_author.uid', 
        $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tx_test_publication_author_mm.uid_foreign')
      )
    )
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
            'tx_test_publication_author_mm.uid_local', 
            $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($uid, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
        )
    )
    ->orderBy('tx_test_domain_model_author.uid', 'ASC');

    $result = $query->execute();
    $res = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $res[] = $row;
    }
    print_r($res);
```

However, I only get one record, although the counter tells me it would be 3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is against the philosophy of Extbase/Fluid. Viewhelpers should not be able to make database queries. You should use a DataProcessor for DB queries.

Answer (score 0):

If the counter says its three items, then try change this:

```
 $result = $query->execute();
 $res = [];
 while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
      $res[] = $row;
 }
```

into this:

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

That fetches all rows into an array that you walk throug with:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the QueryBuilder works differently, this gives me one result namely the first entry in the table:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_test_publication_author_mm');

$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select('*')
    ->from('tx_test_publication_author_mm');

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row['field'];;
}
```

This gives me all results:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName)  or die (mysql_error ());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tx_test_publication_author_mm";
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo $row['field'];
}
```